# Getting Proxy Pac File Contents/Location using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, proxy

I am trying to use Qt 4.8 for proxy resolution, when I have a proxy set in the system configuration under Windows.

My question is that when I set my system settings to use a PAC file, I can use the QNetworkProxyQuery and QNetworkProxy classes to resolve that PAC file for a given domain. However, is there a way I can obtain the actual PAC file contents itself using Qt functionality (or even just the location of the PAC file that is specified in the system settings), rather than have Qt resolve it for me? I know I can use Qt calls to pull down the file manually, but I would have to get the location of the PAC file first as well.

Regards,